# Dont execute javascript again for 1 second, even if trigger is re-triggered

Tags: jquery

Im detecting for scrolling on a page and executing some code when a use scrolls up or down. The problem is that the code is firing multiple times very quickly. I need the code once its executed to not be able to execute again for 1 second.

Ideally any execution would be disabled for 1 second. so if //do something has just fired, then it cant fire again for 1 second and neither can //do something else

Note - I know that this isnt completely reliable cross browser but this is fine for that moment. It also doenst need to work for touchscreen scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            //do something
        }
        else{
            //do something else 
        }
    });
});
```

Ive tried using a timeout function but it seems to wait and then fire multiple times, rather than just once:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //do something 
    event.stopPropagation();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into debounce / throttle. There's a popular [jQuery plug-in](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) which was written by Ben Alman which provides this sort of functionality. See also [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

Debounce or throttle? From the docs:

> Well, to put it simply: while throttling limits the execution of a
>   function to no more than once every delay milliseconds, debouncing
>   guarantees that the function will only ever be executed a single time
>   (given a specified threshhold).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to unbind the event right after the first time you called it and then rebind it with the setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You set a timeout, and then clear that timeout on each scroll, that way the timeout is only executed when the user stops scrolling, and not everytime :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body, html').on('scroll', function(e){
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
        $(this).data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0) {

                }else{
                    //do something else 
                }
            }, 1000)
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out [Underscore's debounce method.](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)